# Resource Not Found error while using master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a designed a web page for late reporting 
(path is:ajax_main/Reporting/LateReporting/LateReport.aspx),
 which works perfectly without a master page.
I have designed a master page
(path is: ajax_main/common/ajax.master)
This is how I call master page in the LateReport.aspx page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Title="Late reporting" 
Debug="true"  MasterPageFile="~/ajax_main/common/Ajax.master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LateReport.aspx.cs"
Inherits="ajax_main_Reporting_LateReport" %>
```

When i run it,  the page displays, but clicking on any button or calendar it shows this error.

> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
>   Requested URL: /adraklive_new/ajax_main/common/LateReport.aspx

The page is directed to the folder "common" where the master page is located,
Anyone can help me solving this error?
Thanks in advance